# Passing JSESSIONID from a SOAP response to a HTTP request in SOAP UI

Tags: groovy, soapui, jsessionid

I have a test case which performs a login via a SOAP request and the response includes this header:

```
Set-Cookie  |   JSESSIONID=85fc792a71f8eb1e2f0e9c63339e; Path=/somepath; HttpOnly
```

After that I have a HTTP request to an URL which only can be accessed if login was succesful.
Although I have set the 'Maintain HTTP session' to true in TestCase Options, the JSESSIONID cookie is not passed to my HTTP request. The HTTP request is performed without a JSESSIONID therefore the response is not the requested URL but the login page. I guess it is because the login process is a SOAP request not HTTP.

I tried to handle the issue with a groovy script: I was able to capture the JSESSIONID from the SOAP response and set it as

```
Cookie  |  JSESSIONID=85fc792a71f8eb1e2f0e9c63339e
```

to my HTTP request but the response is again the login page not the requested page. Any idea how to resolve this issue?
SOAP UI version is 5.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the test case has two test steps with below names:

- step1 (of SOAP Request test step)
- step2 (of HTTP Request test step)

`step1` response contains `Set-Cookie` in response header. And the `step2` needs to send above `Cookie` as part of request headers.

The below `Script Assertion` for `step1` does set `Cookie` to `step2`. Please follow in-line comments.

**Script Assertion:**

```
/**
* This script assertion reads the http response, 
* collect the cookies for the next http request
* Provide the next step name where you want to set the Cookie to the request 
**/

//Change the name of the test step2 below as per your test
def nextStepName = 'step2'

//Assert if the step1 response has headers
assert messageExchange.responseHeaders, "Response does not have headers"

//Get the next request using test step name
def nextRequest = context.testCase.testSteps[nextStepName].httpRequest

//Get the existing headers
def headers = nextRequest.requestHeaders

//Get Cookie from step1 response and create headers
if (messageExchange.responseHeaders.containsKey('Set-Cookie')) {
  log.info "Found Cookie in the response headers"
  def cookiez = messageExchange.responseHeaders['Set-Cookie'].value
  def list = []  
  cookiez.each { cookies ->
     list.add(cookies.toString())
  }
  headers['Cookie'] = list
} else {
  log.warn "Not Found Cookie in the response headers"
}

//Set the headers for step2
nextRequest.requestHeaders = headers
```

**Update 1**

Here is improved `Script Assertion` which allows you to be able to extend very easily:

- to any number of headers from current step response
- to any number of test steps as needed

```groovy
/**
 * This is the Script Assertion
 * which sets headers to the requested  targeted steps
 * by extracting header from current step response
 **/
//Assert if response has headers
assert messageExchange.responseHeaders, "Response does not have any headers"

 //Specify all the headers to retrieve from current test step response as keys, target step request headers as values
 //key - current response header name
 //value - target request header name
 //Add more key, values into map if you need to extract and set more headers
def headerMap = ['Set-Cookie' : 'Cookie']
//Specify the test  step name for which headers to be set. Change step name as needed.
//Add call to setHttpHeaders with different test step names as needed to apply for more steps
setHttpHeaders('step2', headerMap)


/**
  * method sets headers to targeted step
  * step is the step name for which headers to be set
  * header map consists key, header name in the current step and value, header name to appear in the 
  * targeted step
  * 
  **/
def setHttpHeaders(def step, def headerMap) {    
    def nextRequest = context.testCase.testSteps[step]?.httpRequest
    def existingHeaders = nextRequest?.requestHeaders
    headerMap.each {
        existingHeaders[it.value] = getHttpHeaderValue(it.key)
    }
    nextRequest?.requestHeaders = existingHeaders
}

/**
 * method to retrieve the value of the specified header
 **/
def getHttpHeaderValue(def headerToLookup) {    
    if (messageExchange.responseHeaders.containsKey(headerToLookup)) {
        log.info "Found ${headerToLookup} in the response headers"
        return messageExchange.responseHeaders[headerToLookup]
    } else {
        log.warn "${headerToLookup} is not found in the response headers"
    }
    null
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I will check your sollution tomorrow and give you a feedback.

Comment: I tried your script assertion solution. It succesfully sets the headers from step1 (login SOAP resp.) to step2 (the HTTP req.) but it seems the HTTP request ignores it: the response is still the login page instead of the requested page. The HTTP response also have a Set-Cookie header which includes a JSESSIONID but that differs from the one set to the request. I thought it should be the same. Am I wrong? Also the HTTP response has a header called 'Expires' with a value of a date from 1995. Is it possible for the cookies to be already expired before using them?

Comment: Clean the headers for step2, especially, `Cookie` if any. Which one of the above script did you try? You can quickly check in this way: first run step1 only and see what is the value at step2's header.

Comment: May be you can uncheck `Maintain HTTP Session` and try.

Comment: @TamásG.,you may take a look at the above comments and update here.

Comment: I tried the first script. I cleared the Cookie header from step2 (there was not any other). I ran step1 (login) then checked step2's headers. They include the Cookie header with the correct sessionid. But when I run step2, the response is not that I expected. I tried unchecking 'Maintain HTTP Session' but did not solve the issue. I really appreciate your help,

Comment: Can you confirm if the script is setting the same cookie to step2 header that is received in step1 ? Also you can check the raw request and responses for both steps. And see if that differs.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that step1's response's Set-Cookie header contains the same value as the step2's request's Cookie header.

Comment: Ok, do you want try manually by trimming value from the `Set-Cookie` such as `Path=/somepath; HttpOnly` in the second request's header value and see if that helps?

Comment: I ran step1 then edited step2's request's Cookie header to contain only the JSESSIONID. Then ran step2 but it's response is still the same.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and for trying out. Did it work earlier by sending the `sessionid` earlier, even manually? I believe if it can work manually, then we can make it work with the script as well. May be you may check in the application side if there any issue, just to isolate the problem.

Comment: Earlier I have not tried, this is a new test case of two steps. I found out that between two SOAP requests or between two HTTP requests passing the sessionid works just fine with only setting the 'Maintain HTTP Session' option. But between a SOAP and a HTTP request it just doesn't want to pass the correct sessionid, not even when I manually set it to the HTTP request (step2). I guess there might be some other mistake I make here.