# How to handle authentication cookie with SoapUI

Tags: soapui

I'm working on a REST api in SoapUI. I need to be authenticated (token stored in a cookie) to access the desired webservice. I've made a HTTP Request in SoapUI to get the token and extract it from the response. But I'm not sure what to do with it. I tried adding Token to REST request headers, but that didn't do me any good. It was just a blind shot anyway. What should I do with that token? I haven't seen any option for handling cookies in SoapUI.

The full JSON responsee:

```
{"access_token":"4u9Gq5cAGIzZ49VdEj8Amx6Aup0G52ZW_igSlPzCw66vgqvWOKBDEr8Hmz4xcKGK1m7z3X1laaKhqQASNZ5o-j-4tRnEjrVBCfbRj90V5SQOvdPH36UVa-imXWj7kBMkSA3xv4VXAU34TudS8zOu_hDu-17fsf0af9gKy9WCAZauG_A686A14xnAvQz5VUb5DKcFCh3scPGmqJcaParWr95hw_rukOv1uBxtTvyepqCEQaMDES_oQFQoa5tl50YnI0U6MtVH72bkaZV0I5g6ukSRXAhBTxPW8FLRRNAsbhD_a8nDkINQkNyBrV02lkWJR_zXlGseLnyhJ4dygI4SX_eNFjwUa3Elbjr4ZbE7vr5qY0AAEMI_SY5IViL2WNnt",
"token_type":"bearer",
"expires_in":86399,
"AAAIntegratedAuthentication":"False",
"ZZZAccessDefault":"True",
"UserId":"19",
"UserName":"tester",
".issued":"Fri, 21 Oct 2016 10:41:56 GMT",
".expires":"Sat, 22 Oct 2016 10:41:56 GMT"}
```

Thank you Rao! Thanks to reading the other question and some more investigation I found out that I passed the token wrong, I tried do add Token with value of [token] to headers, where I should have been adding Cookie, with value of Token=[token].

Comment: Possibly related, would you please check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059304/passing-jsessionid-from-a-soap-response-to-a-http-request-in-soap-ui?

Comment: I don't see that Set-Cookie thing anywhere in SoapUI. The response after logging in is just a JSON with token and some additional token info, like type, expires, issued, etc.

Comment: In case of other post he was getting that. May be little different you case in terms of getting the token, but second part which is setting Cookie would remain same. Would you please show the structure of your response which contains token? So that can suggest relevantly.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. So, how do you expect it to set in header for next step? just `access_token`? also require `token_type` as well along with? please confirm or how do you currently set manually in order to be able to send the next request successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I was trying to add Token to headers, with the token string as value, where I should really be adding Cookie to headers, with Token=token string as value.

```
HTTP Auth Reques 
transfer access_token from response to $token variable
REST Request with added header Cookie: Token=${token}
```

Et Voila. Thanks to Rao for making me read more stuff.