# how to pass set-cookie value to other request in soapui freeversion - using groovy script

Tags: cookies, groovy, soapui, httponly

I'm testing a REST API which sends set-cookie value in deader response which I need to pass in turn to next subsequent request headers.

Sample set cookie value received from login response.

```
Set-Cookie session-token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJwcmltYXJ5c2lkIjoiNTc4NWIzNGQtNmYyMy00NWJkLWFiN2UtMzgxMzY5NzFjMWU4Iiwic3ViIjoiNTc4NWIzNGQtNmYyMy00NWJkLWFiN2UtMzgxMzY5NzFjMWU4IiwiaXBhIjoiMTI3LjAuMC4xIiwiaWF0IjoxNDg0NzM0MDE1LCJkYXRhIjoiIiwiaXNzIjoiQXRsYXMuTWVtYmVyc2hpcCIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vQXRsYXMuQVBJcyIsImV4cCI6MTQ4NDczNTIxNSwibmJmIjoxNDg0NzM0MDE1fQ.TF3jTSzHnMfqg4rBVEj-UjKUvPsPToWs0iVh_s5ekYUk3mSJP4CyG5r8aD5o01Pm2rCQ_A75gaWMLp10i3OuBscypYoxYYMFX8pVhAOMOeJziWwWBlX3jPyWoJbzEBpUPt8JcQBYAnbgPEBg_pmAfSRnD3R5Lhfrm5CMN0wnre9pTb0aVo8ZPLSl0f7-vFYGsycJEtX7XPsKeThfT4sUConwJqTVPnVpZPid1Z6CnMTHn34i5uKTXWq5Rb4IjWxnSoewTpmG5FNZErv8SOvk1tCSWBMyHXPExakLVwkLozOqLdim2rVyS-FXexFpsSNFCSQw68i2G1tjT2Mb8GFu6g; expires=Wed, 18-Jan-2017 10:26:55 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
```

.

```
def headers = context.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseByName("Authentication").getTestStepByName("RESTReq").testRequest.response.responseHeaders["Set-Cookie"]
def cookie1 = headers.get(0)
def SetCookie1 = cookie1.toString()
SessionToken= SetCookie1.substring(14,692)
log.info SessionToken
context.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("session-token",SessionToken)
```

Further in my next requests, I'm sending this cookies as parameter in the header as

```
Cookie = session-token=${#Project#session-token}
```

But this doesn't work. I'm getting RC=401. Can someone suggest how to handle it in SOAPUI free version?

Comment: Do you want to set cookie for test steps of particular  test case? or for all steps across project / suites? How is the structure of test case in which get the `cookie`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing JSESSIONID from a SOAP response to a HTTP request in SOAP UI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059304/passing-jsessionid-from-a-soap-response-to-a-http-request-in-soap-ui)

Comment: Hi Grisha.. I want the cookie to passed to all of my subsequent requests. At the moment I've got just two requests. 1) Login request 2) Change Passoword Request If I want to change the passowrd I've to login. In login response I'm getting a cookie which needs to be passed in my second request. Even after sending the cookie value I'm getting 401 as the resposne code.

Comment: susithra, have you tried the solution given in the above link?